# How to handle nested JSON in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift4

I'm doing my own decked out "hello world" and I've decided to handle an JSON response from an URL.
I've read a lot of posts on how do handle `JSON` with `Codable` structs but I can't figure out how to create the Codable structs for this nested JSON.

```
{
    "acumulado": "sim",
    "cidades": [],
    "data": "2018-05-02",
    "ganhadores": [
        0,
        91,
        6675
    ],
    "numero": 2036,
    "proximo_data": "2018-05-05",
    "proximo_estimativa": 22000000,
    "rateio": [
        0,
        21948.81,
        427.46
    ],
    "sorteio": [
        7,
        8,
        19,
        23,
        27,
        58
    ],
    "valor_acumulado": 18189847.7
}
```

This is a sample of a JSON returned from the API, how do I create a Codable struct to handle it?
Ps: I know that there are a lot of posts out there that cover this, but I can't figure out how to make it work with my sample.

Comment: There is this cool app called "Paste JSON as Code" and it's free on mac app store, I would definitely recommend it as you will learn a lot from it and get code made.

Comment: I don't see any nesting there

Comment: @user3739902 I'll look into it.

Comment: @Sulthan now that you've mentioned it, maybe thats why I cant put it together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is not really nested:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
   let acumulado: String
   let cidades: [String] // ?? hard to know what data type is there
   let numero: Int
   let proximo_data: String
   let proximo_estimativa: Int
   let rateio: [Double]
   let sorteio: [Int]
   let valor_acumulado: Double
}
```

Every value that can be omitted in the dictionary should be an optional (e.g. `let proximo_data: String?`)

You can also use `CodingKeys` to rename the variables:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
   let acumulado: String
   let cidades: [String] // ?? hard to know what data type is there
   let numero: Int
   let proximoData: String
   let proximoEstimativa: Int
   let rateio: [Double]
   let sorteio: [Int]
   let valorAcumulado: Double

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case acumulado
     case cidades
     case proximoData = "proximo_data"
     case proximoEstimativa = "proximo_estimativa"
     case rateio
     case sorteio
     case valorAcumulado
   }
}
```

Comment: Now that's more like the other posts I've seen out there, It's starting to make sense now lol. I'll take another look into it and if it works I'll accept your answer.
Also, thank you for point out the obvious. :|

Comment: after some minor adjustments, it fits perfectly, thank you!